# Android layout about multiple support screens

Tags: android

i have attached some images using margin and padding. i have done this on samsung galaxy but 
on motorola mile stone, the images are disturbed.

i have already used `<support_screens>` in manifest... but it is not working

Comment: Why anyone upvoted this question is beyond me. Also, what Heiko said. Also, try Googling the exact phrase your question had...

Answer (score 1):

Galaxy screens have their own screen resolutions. there is always an issue with the pixels of galaxy screens. try not to hardcode anything and instead use fill_parent or wrap_content. Hardcoding stuff like margin_Top="355px" varies from handset to handset.

Comment: +1 i also experienced same problem use dip instead of px and use fill_parent and wrap_content. Also use relative more instead of giving fixed margins and width and height.

Comment: i have used dp, wrap_content and relative layout... can yo tell me any solutions

Comment: If using relative layout is a must then go for it...else if you are not specific about your layout then i feel linear is best to stick to